# According to the Catholic Church, can a priest hear a confession over a phone?

Tags: catholicism, communion, confession, covid-19

The Sacrament of Confession is central to Catholic practice, being closely tied to the Sacrament of Holy Communion. During a time of Covid-related lock-down measures and mandates restricting when, where, and how many people legally can gather, many priests have started broadcasting Masses online with Communion available afterwards by walk-up or drive-up distribution. However, confessions are almost purely verbal - there is no need to distribute something. According to the Catholic Church, can the Sacrament of Confession be administered by a priest remotely (over the phone, internet, and so on)?

Comment: My response to this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/82530/can-a-church-pastor-prohibit-sacraments-to-people-for-any-reason-other-than-mor?noredirect=1&lq=1) (**Can a church pastor prohibit sacraments to people for any reason, other than mortal sin?**) deals with this also.